# How to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04?

Tags: installation, 12.04, upgrade

I am using 11.10 and I really want to update to 12.04 but it's impossible.
I cannot see it in the update manager (I did select the option for the releases). I tried `sudo update-manager d`, and `sudo-apt get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get upgrade release d` but nothing. And `sudo do-release-upgrade` is not working as well! (I get "no release found" message.)

So finally I did put on a live USB and when I boot, I click on install, then it's telling me that I do have 11.10 and I can select for erase all and install Ubuntu 12.04 or I can install along 11.10 and the second option to update 11.10 to 12.04 is grey. I cannot selected it! Why? Am I running out of options?

What else can I do to upgrade to 12.04?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo do-release-upgrade`?

Comment: It's not working it's telling me no release found !!!! I am going crazy

Comment: Ok, what's the output of `cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`?

Comment: @SirCharlo  Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]                                                        #           determine if a newer release is available.
prompt=lts

Comment: Ok, then try `sudo sed -i 's/lts/normal/g' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades; sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Why are you trying to upgrade to 12.10? Latest release is 12.04, and I think that 12.10 is in a too early stage to be tested

Comment: @Pisu yeah sorry i tried to install 12.04 sorry and not 12.10

Comment: @SirCharlo thanks , i am doing it now  and it's deleting packages , installing and upgrade packages! Thanks a lot ! any idea why it wasnt working before?

Comment: @SirCharlo Can you add that as an answer or something? Thanks!

Comment: Consider it done! :)